# Find cells with maximum value per dimension in stars object (R)

Tags: raster, r, sf, terra, stars

I would like to find the cells, and their corresponding centroid, that hold the maximum value for each band in a multiband raster.

Converting the `stars`-object to a `sf`-dataframe makes this easy somehow. But I also think this is super unefficient. And I have the strong feeling that this is an easy task which I can't figure out how to do... (using subsetting, `st_apply`, `aggregate`, ....)

This is the code (using the conversion to a `sf`-table)

```
library(stars)
library(sf)
tif = system.file("tif/L7_ETMs.tif", package = "stars")
x = read_stars(tif)
# for each cell find the geolocated-cell with the highest value 
df = st_as_sf(x)
max_per_band = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -geometry
  ) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  filter(value==max(value))

st_centroid(max_per_band)

            geometry name           value
 *        <POINT [m]> <chr>          <dbl>
 1   (288990 9119179) L7_ETMs.tif.V5   255
 2   (288990 9119179) L7_ETMs.tif.V6   255
 3 (297511.5 9118239) L7_ETMs.tif.V5   255
 4 (297511.5 9118239) L7_ETMs.tif.V6   255
 5   (296457 9117925) L7_ETMs.tif.V6   255
 6 (294376.5 9117127) L7_ETMs.tif.V5   255
 7 (294376.5 9117127) L7_ETMs.tif.V6   255
 8   (294348 9117099) L7_ETMs.tif.V1   255
 9   (294348 9117099) L7_ETMs.tif.V2   255
10   (294348 9117099) L7_ETMs.tif.V3   255
```

Comment: `terra` has the convenient `where.max` function which gets you 90% of the way there (returns cell numbers, but you can get coords when needed). You can convert stars to terra with `terra::rast` or work natively in `terra`?

Comment: sorry for the late question... Can I get the coords directly with that function or do I need to use the cell-index?

Comment: I hesitated to make an answer with this because you are using `stars` in the Q and not terra. If terra is an option for you, how about making a new question and then we'll have solutions in stars (if the answer below is an answer, in which case it needs marking as accepted) and in terra....

Comment: ah yes of course! Sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take advantage of the fact that the representation of a `stars` object in R is an array so we can get the indices of cells where the band values are equal to the maximum value of the respective band. The code below then constructs an `sf` object by querying the coordinates of the cell centroids at the respective indices.

```r
library(stars)
#> Loading required package: abind
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(sf)

tif = system.file("tif/L7_ETMs.tif", package = "stars")
(x = read_stars(tif))
#> stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
#> attribute(s):
#>              Min. 1st Qu. Median     Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
#> L7_ETMs.tif     1      54     69 68.91242      86  255
#> dimension(s):
#>      from  to  offset delta                     refsys point x/y
#> x       1 349  288776  28.5 SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 25S FALSE [x]
#> y       1 352 9120761 -28.5 SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 25S FALSE [y]
#> band    1   6      NA    NA                         NA    NA

x_dims <- st_get_dimension_values(x, which = 1, where = "center")
y_dims <- st_get_dimension_values(x, which = 2, where = "center")

band_max_indices <- apply(x[[1]], 3, function(x) which(x == max(x) , arr.ind = TRUE))

locs <- lapply(1:length(band_max_indices), function(i){
  band <- band_max_indices[[i]]
  m <- matrix(c(
    x_dims[band[ ,1]],
    y_dims[band[ ,2]]
  ), ncol = 2)
  
  p <- st_as_sf(as.data.frame(m), 
                coords = c(1,2), 
                crs = st_crs(x))
  
  p$band <- i
  p$x_index <- band[ ,2]
  p$y_index <- band[ ,1]
  p$value <- st_extract(x, p)[[1]][,i]
  p
})

(locs <- do.call(rbind, locs))
#> Simple feature collection with 61 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 288990 ymin: 9110914 xmax: 297511.5 ymax: 9119179
#> Projected CRS: SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 25S
#> First 10 features:
#>    band x_index y_index value                 geometry
#> 1     1     129     196   255   POINT (294348 9117099)
#> 2     1     129     197   255 POINT (294376.5 9117099)
#> 3     1     318     182   255   POINT (293949 9111712)
#> 4     1     318     183   255 POINT (293977.5 9111712)
#> 5     1     319     180   255   POINT (293892 9111684)
#> 6     1     319     181   255 POINT (293920.5 9111684)
#> 7     1     319     182   255   POINT (293949 9111684)
#> 8     1     320     180   255   POINT (293892 9111655)
#> 9     1     320     181   255 POINT (293920.5 9111655)
#> 10    1     320     183   255 POINT (293977.5 9111655)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>