# Find locations (cell's centroid) of a raster's min and max value using R and terra

Tags: r, extract, terra

I have a raster like this one:
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1AEKu4TKpzJg95oXv8dxep24xpXaesr0F

I want to find the locations (can be the centroid or the bounding box of these cells) for the extreme values (minimum and maximum).

[Here is a great answer on how to do it using `stars`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/469329/find-cells-with-maximum-value-per-dimension-in-stars-object-r/469426#469426)

However, I wonder how to do it quickly using `terra`

There are the `where.min` and `where.max`, as well as the `minmax` functions. Yet they return the cell-index and the value, not the coordinates though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read raster using `terra`:

```
r = rast("au.tif")
```

Get coords of minimum:

```
xyFromCell(r, where.min(r)[2])

##           x      y
## [1,] 377500 393500
```

Breaking this down a bit, `where.min` returns the layer, cell number, and value there:

```
> where.min(r)
     layer   cell   value
[1,]     1 101114 1265075
```

If you have a multi-layer raster then you get the second column of the `where.min`:

Make 3 layers:

```
> r3 = c(r,r,r)
```

Splash a zero into each of the first two layers:

```
> r3[100,100,1]=0
> r3[200,200,2]=0
```

Then see:

```
> xyFromCell(r3, where.min(r3)[,2])
          x      y
[1,] 211500 470500
[2,] 311500 370500
[3,] 377500 393500
```

If you have multiple equal minima per layer, then you might want to record the layers alongside the locations...

Stick another zero in layer 2:

```
> r3[200,100,2]=0
```

Get the `where.min` matrix and use column 2 to get the coords info and then splat the matrix on it as well using `cbind`:

```
> wm = where.min(r3)
> cbind(xyFromCell(r3, wm[,2]), wm)
          x      y layer   cell   value
[1,] 211500 470500     1  56827       0
[2,] 211500 370500     2 114127       0
[3,] 311500 370500     2 114227       0
[4,] 377500 393500     3 101114 1265075
```